# setInterval () включать и отключать

Tags: php, javascript

Написал на php код, который обращается к базе данных. Php файл запускается с помощью

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('#myClass').load("new.php");
}, 40000);
```

Этот скрипт будет запускаться на Joomla в материалах с доступом на 3 человека. Вопрос: могут ли произойти сбои или зависания из-за  3 постоянных (40000 млс ) обращения к серверу ? 
Как отключать  setInterval  при переходе на другую страницу и после возвращения   включать?

Comment: Вы просто каждые 40 минут обращаетесь к скрипту, который теребит базу данных. Ничего произойти не должно. Даже если уменьшить до 5-10 секунд.

Comment: спасибо, а как отключать и выключать   setInterval если я перехожу на другую страницу и возвращаюсь. Надо  чтоб когда переходил на другую страницу отключалась а когда переходил на этот включалась

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо сам разобрался!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var interval = setInterval(function() {$('#divClass').load("new.php");}, 5000);

$(window).on('blur', function(){
    clearInterval(interval)
});

$(window).on('focus', function(){
    interval = setInterval(function() {$('#divClass').load("new.php");}, 5000)
});
```